# Lost GTFS result routes using GraphHopper

Tags: java, gtfs, graphhopper

I’ve developed GTFS routing application using `GraphHopper` (*Open Source Routing Engine*) but I’ve got a problem. According to departure time I’ve got different best routes but I can’t get alternative routes in some cases.
For example when I request routes for all vehicle types then I receive only 2 result routes (subway and walk) but all alternative routes (with bus, tram, trolley legs) have lost. If I execute this request for all vehicle types excluding subway then result contains another 2 routes.

For configuring request vehicle type I use `Request.setBlockedRouteTypes()`. I noticed that `GraphHopper` finds all possible routes but hides alternatives in some cases.
So I need to:

- configure `GraphHopperGtfs` (may be `Request`) to get all the results in 1 response (including all alternatives)
- find PMap keys description (source code or docs) for configuring request (e.g. maximum result count, minimum / maximum transfer time).

Thanks!

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I want to get all possible routes (for all vehicle types) per 1 request.